# Trying to save Data to an accessible file on an android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, save

i have mentioned this in previous questions, I am currently using shared preferences to store some results of a BLE scan (RSSI and Time of scan) within the app. This works and the most recent scan data is accessible via an onclick button.

What i actually want is for all the scans to be stored in a file that is accessible externally from the app (Not to be confused with an external storage such as SD card). I am not using an emulator, i am using a Samsung galaxy s8 on Android 9. I have looked at some tutorials such as :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTYR3FBDus4 (3Mins)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcfUkjlL9RI (11Mins)

And i was wondering if this "FileOutputstream onclick method" could be interpreted to store all the scanned information, for me to then access through the data file directory?

I noticed that in the first link example,  showed the file to be accessible through the emulator as a .txt file. Can the same be done when using an actual android device?

EDIT: Addition of file Output stream code

```
                FileOutputStream fos = null;

                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(FileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(RSSI1);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved To: " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FileName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    if (fos!=null){
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

New Code:

```
//To create file path 
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Data");
            if (!file.mkdirs()){
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            String FilePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FileName;



//to print data to file in filepath
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FilePath);
                    fileOutputStream.write(RSSI1);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory saved is : " + getFilesDir(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Which app(s) should be able to access the file?

Comment: @blackapps Well other than the BLE scanner app that displays the scan immediately, None. I have been asked to get the data of the scans to store on the phone storage, Not in an app from my understanding.

Comment: Unclear. Is that the app that writes the file? Has the file to be read by a different app then the app that created the file?

Comment: So the BLE scanner app (my only app) is currently receiving and displaying data from a transmission. That data is the data I want to store (so write to a file using the BLE scanner app).  This file ideally would be stored in a way that allows it to be opened whilst not using the BLE scanner app, So just a file on the phones accessible storage (Like a txt file on a laptop in a folder) that allows it to be opened on the phone (like a downloaded picture is stored on a phone)  Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Wel then the other app would be a file explorer or a file manager.

Comment: Save your file to getExternalStorageDirectory() or a subfolder of it or getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). Do not use a hard coded path that you saw in a file explorer or so. If people advise you to do so sew them!

Comment: @blackapps does the getExternalStorageDirectory() require an external storage however? Such as an SD card. I tried using the method in the answer below (See edited code in question) and used FileOutputstream, my toast message says the file has been saved in a directory. however the file is not in that directory!

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() is always available and has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. For help with the answer below please call the poster. You know my opinion of that answer. And why do you mark that answer as problem solved? And if it does not work then why that thank you so much? Pretty confusing. And why the upvoting?

Comment: well at the time when my toast came up saying the file was saved, i thought it worked, thats when i made edits to the post. Its only today after trying to locate the file i see it didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236397/discussion-between-gazza-and-blackapps).

Comment: No i will not chat. Please chat with Andrea about that answer.

Comment: Okay, thats fair my question to you would have been in regards to using Getexternal storage not andreas answer but thats fine

Comment: Well post code where you use that function and im back. Post it in a new code block.